# How to ListContourPlot an eigenvalue spectrum without jumping?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, filtering, sorting, eigenvalues

**MWE:**

```
Block[{dim = 4, grain = 250, matrix, domain, spectrum, locus},

matrix = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Sqrt[(x + 1/2 - (1 + Exp[-(i - 1)])^(-1))^2 +
   (y (1 + Exp[-2 (i - 1)])^(-1))^2], {i, 1, dim}]];
domain = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 2./(grain - 1)}, {y, -1, 1,2./(grain - 1)}], 1];
spectrum = Table[Append[σ, Sort@Re@Eigenvalues[ReplaceAll[matrix, {x -> σ[[1]], 
    y -> σ[[2]]}]]], {σ, domain}];
locus[energy_] := Table[Join[spectrum[[σ, 1 ;;2]], Take[SortBy[spectrum[[σ, 3]], 
    Abs[# - energy] &],1]], {σ, 1, Length@domain}]; 

ListContourPlot[locus[0.1], Contours -> {0.1}, InterpolationOrder -> 4] /. 
    _Polygon -> Sequence[]

]
```

This code block functions roughly as desired, but the quality of the plot is very bad and cannot be satisfactorily improved by increasing `grain` and `InterpolationOrder`. Clearly, in this example matrix, the contours should be smooth ellipses and we need to recover that to a higher fidelity.

The `matrix` here is a toy, the only real constraint on the matrix I need to preserve is that it must be Hermitian and depend on two independent, real variables.

My solution attempt:

1. discretizes the `domain` into a mesh of (x,y) points
2. collects into array `spectrum` a `dim`-dimensional eigenvalue-list (of real numbers) at every point in the `domain`
3. Defines a function `locus` which reduces the `spectrum` array to include only a single eigenvalue (rather than `dim`-many) at every point in the `domain`.
4. Perform a `ListContourPlot` of the `locus`

However, I believe that the `Take` of the "correct" eigenvalue in step 3 eigenvalue at every point in the domain is likely the source of the problem.

In my MWE, I `Take` the eigenvalue which is absolutely nearest to the function argument `energy`. However, I can envision several pathological function landscapes which break this selection and, indeed, the plots illustrate this problem.

**The goal of the code is to plot a level set (contour) of all points where there is *any* eigenvalue of the `matrix`**

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39747) is related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see what is happening here, first plot a blow-up of the 2D region to show clearly the contours.

```
ListContourPlot[locus[0.1], Contours -> {0.1}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
    ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.6}, {-0.4, 0.4}}]
```

[image]

The plot appears to consist of four ellipses plus two ragged curves.  Note that `InterpolationOrder -> 1` is used instead of `4`, as in the question, to avoid any possible oscillations in the interpolation, which could occur near discontinuities.  Note also, that `ContourShading -> None` is used to display contours only.  The question used `/. _Polygon -> Sequence[]` instead, but the latter may be less transparent to some readers.

To clarify the nature of the ragged curves, next plot a slice through the 2D region, for instance, `y == 0`.

```
ListPlot[Delete[#, 2] & /@ Select[locus[0.1], Abs[#[[2]]] < .01 &], 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.6}, {0, .2}}]
```

[image]

With this plot aligned with the first, it is evident that the two ragged curves are associated with discontinuities in `locus[0.1]`.  [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) suggested in a comment a related [1-D problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39747) in which the solution was to sort eigenvalues to produce continuous arrays.  The following seems more straightforward in 2D, however: Plot contours for each of the four sets of eigenvalues and superimpose them.  This works well, because `Eigenvalues` sorts the eigenvalues it produces by size, and those eigenvalues vary smoothly with `{x, y}` except where the eigenvalues intersect.

```
eig[n_] := Extract[#, {{1}, {2}, {3, n}}] & /@ spectrum    
Show @@ (ListContourPlot[eig[#], Contours -> {0.1}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
    ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.6}, {-0.4, 0.4}}] & /@ Range[1, 4])
```

[image]

as desired

Answer (score 4):

I want to give a big thanks to user bbgodfrey for the elegant solution to the problem posed.

However, for variety and extension, I'm posting this answer in addition. Basically, I modified his/her solution by

1. exchanging `Append` to `Join` in `spectrum` definition
2. exchanging `Map,Extract` to `Part` in what would be the definition of `eig`
3. forgoing definition of `eig` in favor of building that functionality into the `ListContourPlot`
4. exchanging `Show, Apply` to `Show, Table` in the `ListContourPlot`
5. including plotting qualities in the function

The majority of these changes are aesthetic, simply because I don't have a lot of experience coding with `Map` and `Apply`, so they aren't intuitive. The last point is a simple extension that is beyond the scope of the question I posed here but I include only for other interested readers.

```
Block[{dim = 4, grain = 250, matrix, domain, range, cuts, spectrum, colors},
matrix = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Sqrt[(x + 1/2 - (1 + Exp[-(i - 1)])^(-1))^2 + (y (1 + Exp[-2 (i - 1)])^(-1))^2], {i, 1, dim}]];
domain = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 2./(grain - 1)}, {y, -1, 1,2./(grain - 1)}], 1];  
range = Range[0, 0.15, 0.15/(cuts - 1)];  
spectrum = Table[Join[\[Sigma],Sort@Re@Eigenvalues[ReplaceAll[matrix, {x -> \[Sigma][[1]],y -> \[Sigma][[2]]}]]], {\[Sigma], domain}];

discreteConPlot[energy_, quality_] := Show@Table[
ListContourPlot[spectrum[[All, {1, 2, \[Sigma] + 2}]], 
 ContourStyle -> {quality[[1]], Thickness[quality[[2]]]}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> quality[[3]], ImageSize -> quality[[4]], 
 Contours -> {energy}, ContourShading -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.6}, {-0.4, 0.4}}], {\[Sigma], 1, dim}];

colors = Table[Hue[\[Sigma], 1, 0.7], {\[Sigma], Range[0, 0.8, 0.8/(cuts -1)]}];

ListAnimate[
Table[discreteConPlot[range[[s]], {colors[[s]], 0.005, 1, 400}], {s,1, Length@range}]
, AnimationRunning -> False]

]
```

This block produces `cuts`-many contours across the `range` of values chosen, with a hue-spread across `Hue[0,1,0.7]` to `Hue[0.8,1,0.7]` and other qualities that can be adjusted readily.

Several of the `Table` throughout this algorithm can likely be improved by `Parallelization` but the optimal choice may depend on the user's machine and the size of `dim` and `grain`, amongst others.

Example output, by exchanging `ListAnimate` here for `Show`.

[image]