# Find the area enclosed by a loop in an image (Contour in a plot)

Tags: image-processing, image

Is there a way to simply compute the area enclosed by a line in an image, like this:

[image]

Here's an example of what I mean by a few of the "enclosed regions"

[image]

**Solution 1**

These sorts of images are produced on my end by a `ListContourPlot` of some functions, so in principle I have a mesh of domain points and associated function values. However, importantly, this doesn't give me exactly the points show in these contours, which are found by `ListContourPlot`. In principle, I suppose I could construct some method for manually finding all these points and using Green's Theorem to construct a numerical approximation of the areas. This would be a ton of work.

**Solution 2**

I feel like there should surely be an easier way to find these areas in post-processing/image processing. The lines are all a single, known, hue, as is the background between. I don't know where to start on this method, but hopefully you can help!

Comment: Would you mind including the code that generated the contour plot so people can base their answers on it?

Comment: The code that generated those images is long and obfuscated, but it is based on the solution to a previous question of mine, here, so feel free to solve this problem based on that as well. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111871/how-to-listcontourplot-an-eigenvalue-spectrum-without-jumping/111881#111881

Comment: @Steve - the contours that MarcoB is using to work out this below have many fully closed regions, whereas your plot has many **almost** closed regions.  Are you interested in being able to select a portion of the image and have that whatever closed region that is part of?

Comment: Also, I have an easy way for you to give us the code for your plot.  Run all the commands that generate the plot, then after it has been generated type `CopyToClipboard@InputForm@Normal@%`, then go to gist.github.com and paste the result there, and link the result here.  It would be something like [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/6458a48c9fd4d2484bb77bd74899e93d/raw/5c8737422c84b81edb6631d43c74ece6bba7f665/gistfile1.txt)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick attempt using morphological image analysis on my own contour plot, since you did not provide yours:

1. Generate a contour plot with some closed contours and style it more or less like yours:

   ```
   contour = ContourPlot[
     Sin[2 x]^2 - Cos[2 y]^2, {x, y} ∈ Polygon[CirclePoints[{1, 90 Degree}, 6]],
     PlotPoints -> 75, Contours -> 4,
     ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker@Blue],
     BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black},
     PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
   ]
   ```

[image: contour plot]

2. Calculate the morphological components of the image (I pre-emptively remove the frame of the graph to avoid confusion):

   ```
   components = WatershedComponents[Show[contour, Frame -> False]]
   Colorize[components]
   ```

[image: watershed components]

3. Measure the area of the identified components:

   ```
   ComponentMeasurements[components, "Area"]

   (* Out: {1 -> 91741.8, 2 -> 17916.5, 3 -> 11013.3, 4 -> 7016.} *)
   ```

---

In case you don't have `CirclePoints` in your version, replace it in the code above with:

```
{
  {0, 1}, {-(Sqrt[3]/2), 1/2}, 
  {-(Sqrt[3]/2), -(1/2)}, {0, -1}, 
  {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2)}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}
}
```

Comment: What are you saving as variable "`contour`"?

Comment: @Steve The ContourPlot itself. Sorry, I lost that in copy / paste, but I added it back in now.

Comment: Hmm. So I can't directly test your solution in version 9.0 because of `CirclePoints`, and so far my attempts at applying your solution directly to my image have been unsuccessful.

Comment: @Steve I added the output of my `CirclePoints` expression, so you can test it on v.9. Also, I wanted to try this method out on your contours, put I couldn't immediately find where that contour plot you show was generated in the question you linked. Could you expand on that in your question?

Comment: Yes, I'll expand on that. Also, this is what it's doing for me on the other contours: http://i.imgur.com/OrCQaG7.png

Comment: Is this what you meant by directly testing your output? http://i.imgur.com/HZ7qxsU.png

Comment: @Steve That doesn't look right. The outputs I get from the code are shown in my answer, and they are definitely different. It almost looks like the frame was still present when the image was fed into `WatershedComponents`. Can you run `Show[contour, Frame -> False]` on its own and check that the frame / axes are correctly removed?

Comment: Yeah, without running the `ContourPlot`, it can't remove the frame. Nonetheless, it's still not working for me after fixing that bt replacing the `CirclePoints` problem by just making it a square for now, and get http://i.imgur.com/vxQIzWO.png

Comment: @Steve [This is what I get on MMA 10.4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NFacz.png) in the case of the square domain you suggested; I guess `WatershedComponents` has been modified / upgraded since version 9. Unfortunately I don't have access to version 9 to test further.